# TypeError: Can't convert 'module' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I want to classify this Dataframe(named:loandata) and import each sub-dataframe into many csv files. The first step, I try to convert one of the results, but unfortunately failed and got this error:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os

#readfile
loandata=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_table('/Users/lixuefei/Desktop/Sample Dataset/test.txt',header = None,index_col=2))

#classify
volume_type=list(set(loandata[3]))
system_type=list(set(loandata[4]))
area_name=list(set(loandata[5]))

df=pd.DataFrame(loandata[(loandata[3]==volume_type[0])& (loandata[4]==system_type[0])&(loandata[5]==area_name[0])])
#set the file path
path='/Users/lixuefei/Desktop/Sample Dataset'
filename=volume_type[0]+system_type[0]+area_name[0]
filetype=csv

if not df.empty:
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(path,filename+filetype),header=None)
else:
    print("Empty")
```

and this is the Error:

```
/Users/lixuefei/anaconda/bin/python3.5/Users/lixuefei/PycharmProjects/project/project.11.09.py
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/lixuefei/PycharmProjects/project/project.11.09.py", line 25, in <module>
       df.to_csv(os.path.join(path,filename+filetype),header=None)
   TypeError: Can't convert 'module' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: you assign module to variable `filetype=csv` - you forgot `""` - `filetype="csv"` or maybe event `filetype=".csv"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) whitespace is your friend.

b) `filename` is a string, `filetype` is the csv module.

I think what you meant to say is:

```
filetype = "csv"
```

Then one of the below:

```
os.path.join(path, filename + "." + filetype)
```

or better yet:

```
os.path.join(path, "%s.%s" % (filename, filetype))
```

or the "proper" Python 3 way:

```
os.path.join(path, "{}.{}".format(filename, filetype))
```